# How to set GOMOD in MacOS

Tags: macos, go

I'm using this cmd to set `GOMOD` in `.zshrc` file:

```
unset GOMOD &&  go env -w GOMOD=$HOME/MyProj/Proj1/go.mod
```

But receive error:

```
go env -w: GOMOD cannot be modified
```

How to fix it?

Comment: why do you need to set the go.mod file manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GOMOD` variable is specific to module (project) so it makes sense it is not allowed to be written to default env which is shared for all modules and stored in your `os.UserConfigDir()/go/env` (e.g. `~/.config/go/env`).

You don't need to set `GOMOD`, `go` tool will find `go.mod` file in project repo root and infer value of `GOMOD` for reading from `go env` output.

If you for some reason need to tell `go` command about alternative mod file you need to use `GOFLAGS=-modfile path/to/alt.go.mod` instead of setting `GOMOD` directly. In such case top-level `go.mod` still must exist (but will not be used). You can see how it works in this Go test driver script [`modfile_flag.txt`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/testdata/script/modfile_flag.txt).